# Segmentation fault but can't find the bug

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char str[200];
    int nn;
    struct node* next;
};

int number;
struct node* start=NULL;
struct node* current;
//function to insert into the list 

void insert() {
    struct node* n;
    n=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->str=malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
    printf("please enter the data that you would like to insert: ");
    gets(n->str);
    printf("asdasdasdasd");
    n->next=NULL;
    if( start==NULL ) {
        start->next=n;
        current=n;
    }
    else {

    current->next=n;
    current=n;

    }

    printf("done\n");
}

void display() {
    current=start;
    int i=0;
    while( current->next!=NULL ) {
        printf("node%d= %s\n",++i,current->str);
        current=current->next;

    }
    printf("this the end");
}


int main() {
    char c;
    int input;

    do {
        printf("Select from the following options:\n"
           "1.Display list\n"
           "2.Add to list\n"
           "3.delete from list\n");

        scanf("%d",&input);
        switch (input) {
            case 1: display(); break;
            case 2: insert(); break;
      //    case 3: delete(); break;
            default : printf("Please select 1 , 2 or 3\n");
        }
        printf( "would you like to continue?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%s",&c);
    } while(c=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

This is giving me an error in the insert function, A SEGMENTATION FAULT !

I Tried things but I just don't get the clear picture. I am a bit weak with pointers, actually confused !

Please help me out by telling me what I am doing wrong. Forget about my linked list logic, let it be wrong. I just wanna know why a segmentation fault is occurring !

Comment: This isn't the code you run and got the segmentation fault from. This code has an assignment to an array which prevents it from compiling.

Comment: 1. Indent your code. 2. Have you managed to compile that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have many mistakes, but your crash is because you don't allocate start

```
n->next=NULL;
    if( start==NULL ) {
        start->next=n;
        current=n;
    }
    else {

    current->next=n;
    current=n;
```

you ask if start is null, and if it is you try to read it by calling start->next it. you need to allocate it first.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not tell us the line in which your segfault happened, I can only guess.

At least these lines sounds bogus to me:

```
if( start==NULL ) {
    start->next=n;
    current=n;
}
```

Are you sure that you want to dereference `start` when it is `NULL`? That is what you are doing with `start->next`. Dereferencing `NULL` causes a segfault.

Maybe this will work the way you expect it:

```
if( start==NULL ) {
    start=n;
    current=n;
}
```

So basically, if `start` was not defined yet, define it and it also becomes your current item.

Comment: i was getting an error at the malloc line in insert function, which din make much sense. but what you pointed out is right !!
Thanks

Comment: Then you could simply change your `struct node { char str[200];...` to `struct node { char* str;...`. I was actually wondering at this line: `n->str=malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);` but I was not sure if I should have commented on that :P. You declare your `str` as automatic but you allocate the memory dynamically...

Comment: Initially i started off with 
    struct node {
        char* str; ... } 
but when i was allocating memory using malloc for this char pointer i had some difficulty so i changed it to char array. I will try it again and shall let you know if i am getting an error ...thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Compilation Error
   `n->str=malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);`

   > and this is address reassign on a constant!!!!!You are changing the address of array???
2. Dangerous Function with 25% probability to execute.

   `gets(n->str);`
3. Setting value at null pointer!!!

   `struct node* start=NULL;....

    start->next=n;`

Example of working Code

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node {
        char *str;
        int nn;
        struct node* next;
        };

    int number;
    struct node* start=NULL;
    struct node* current;
    //function to insert into the list

    void insert() {
        struct node* n;
        n=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
        printf("please enter the data that you would like to insert: ");
        scanf("%s",n->str);
        printf("asdasdasdasd");
        n->next=NULL;
        if( start==NULL ) {
            //start->next=n;
            current=n;
        }
        else {

        current->next=n;
        current=n;

        }

        printf("done\n");
    }

    void display() {
        current=start;
        int i=0;
        while( current->next!=NULL ) {
            printf("node%d= %s\n",++i,current->str);
            current=current->next;

        }
        printf("this the end");
        }


    int main() {

        char c;
        int input;

        do {
            printf("Select from the following options:\n"
               "1.Display list\n"
               "2.Add to list\n"
               "3.delete from list\n"
               );


        scanf("%d",&input);
        switch (input) {

            case 1: display(); break;
            case 2: insert(); break;
        //    case 3: delete(); break;
            default : printf("Please select 1 , 2 or 3\n");

            }
        printf( "would you like to continue?(y/n)\n");
        scanf("%s",&c);
        }while(c=='y');

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: But you are also using n->str=malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000); in your working code !!

Comment: Will this work while accessing a linked list ? 
...  (start->next)->next .... I know it does not work but is there a way to do this without the use of an other structure ?

Comment: @hunterr986:- why dont you put `if( start==NULL ) {
            start=n;
            current=start;
        }` :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use debugger (not us) in order to find more information about the problem.

For example gdb ([GNU Debuger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger)).

Answer (score 1):

```
if( start==NULL ) {
        start->next=n;
        current=n;
    }
```

I think you have a little problem here ;-)

Comment: hmmm .... i assigned the structure to NULL in the beginning of the code. so that check should now do anything right ? Please correct me here.. Thanks

Comment: @hunterr986 problem is accessing start->next when start is NULL

Answer (score 1):

the next line is not safe:

```
   scanf("%s",&c);
```

scanf adds terminating null character '\0' that corrupts stack in your case.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know !
but whenever i used getchar() the program was terminating immediately whenever it reached that line in code. so i used scanf to make it work !